# Html h3 tag href

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can I make just the word back clickble? 

 Not also the whole space to the left.

```
  <div style="border: 2px solid;text-align:right" class="row" >
        <a class='btn btn-link'  href='#'><h3>back</h3></a>
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0mfmzz27/)

Comment: Please try a.btn-link { display: inline-block; }

Answer (score 3):

Your `h3` element is being displayed as a block, which is making it give full width.

You can do it either two ways. First, you can change the order of your `a` tags:

```
<h3><a class='btn btn-link' href='#'>back</a></h3>
```

Or you can just add `display:inline-block` to your CSS file for the `h3` tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/0mfmzz27/4/

Answer (score 1):

Just don't wrap it around h3 tag. use your own custom class with font-size to give the bigger text appearence.

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
<div style="border: 2px solid;text-align:right" class="row" >
   <h3><a class='btn btn-link'  href='#'>back</a></h3>
</div>
```

instead